ubuntu server 24.04 print [0.004s] or bash: 1716451538,009859: value too great for base (error token is "009859") each command
I've just installed ubuntu server 24.04 on bare metall. After each command terminal print "time" in square brakets:
[0.004s] 

like
[0.006s] andrey@bonanza-server:~/iso$ rm -r ./*
[0.-55s] andrey@bonanza-server:~/iso$

or
bash: 1716451538,009859: value too great for base (error token is "009859")  each command 

How to disable printing this?

Where did strict=0 come from in declare -p PS1 PROMPT_COMMANDstrict=0?

Did none of the google results for https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+value+too+great+for+base+error+token help you?

Actually - are you asking for help to fix the error message that you sometimes get when your prompt is printing the time or are you asking for help to stop your prompt from containing the time? If the latter, just set PS1='$ ' in your profile and then log in again.

It looks like the issue is related to a byobu_prompt_runtime function, which was likely added to your ~/.bashrc by byobu - see for example byobu/blob/master/usr/share/byobu/profiles/bashrc

... if I had to guess the cause of the error, it would be that your locale is causing byobi to record the time in $BYOBU_RUN_DIR/timer.$$ using , as the decimal separator - whereas the byobu_prompt_runtime only expects . (i.e. starttime=${starttime/./} presumably to convert decimal micorseconds to integer nanoseconds)

I think @steeldriver is right, but it's probably somwhere else as we excluded ~/.bashrc already - try and check locations typically sourced by a login shell: grep -l 'byobu_prompt_status' /etc/profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile

Although it'd perhaps make more sense for one of those locations to conditionally source the file steeldriver linked, maybe it'd make more sense if you inspected them manually.

@steeldriver you re right !!!! Thanks I ll post solution.

I've found solution. TO disable printing command execution we can delete function call named byobu_prompt_runtime from /usr/share/byobu/profiles/bashrc.
Example:
# Use Ubuntu colors (grey / orange / aubergine)
export PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[38;5;202m\]\$(byobu_prompt_status)\[\e[00m\]\$(byobu_prompt_runtime)\[\e[38;5;245m\]\u\[\e[00m\]@\[\e[38;5;172m\]\h\[\e[00m\]:\[\e[38;5;5m\]\w\[\e[00m\]\$(byobu_prompt_symbol )"

                    

We should delete $(byobu_prompt_runtime) to have:
# Use Ubuntu colors (grey / orange / aubergine)
export PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[38;5;202m\]\[\e[00m\]\[\e[38;5;245m\]\u\[\e[00m\]@\[\e[38;5;172m\]\h\[\e[00m\]:\[\e[38;5;5m\]\w\[\e[00m\]\$(byobu_prompt_symbol) "


That looks like a good workaround - however IMHO it would be worth submitting a bug report that byobu_prompt_runtime should be made locale-aware

Thanks for your opinion about a bug report. But I don't understand why somebody need with printing command runtime.
